# elixir function taking a parameter with do

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to wrap my head around Elixir and am confused about the following

```
def fun_myfunc(clause, do: expression) do
```

Specifically I'm a bit confused about the `do: expression` part.  Is this a parameter being passed into the function, and also why is there a `:`.  Is `do` a keyword in this context ?

This also gives rise to the following, question on `Phoenix`.  If I look at the pipeline function https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#pipeline/2 I see the following signature `pipeline(plug, list)`.  What is `list` in this context and how do I infer it by looking at the documentation.  I know that they have given examples where `list` looks like a bunch of expressions, but how do I gather that just by looking at the documentaion.

Answer (score 1):

`do: expression` is a [keyword list](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#fetch/). This is syntax sugar in two forms:

- As the last parameter to a function, you can omit the surrounding `[]`
- As a keyword list, you can write `key: value` instead of the equivalent `{:key, :value}`

Both of these are documented in the above link.

The function is equivalent to:

```
def fun_myfunc(clause, [{:do, expression}]) do
```

The `:do` is simply an atom. It's up to the `fun_myfunc` to decide how to handle it.

I suspect you are actually looking at a macro defined with `defmacro` and misquoted it in your question. This is also how the [`if` macro](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/0909940b04a3e22c9ea4fedafa2aac349717011c/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3709-L3731) works, for example.

`if foo do bar else baz` is equivalent to `if(foo, do: bar, else: baz)`, which is equivalent to `if(foo, [{:do, bar}, {:else, baz}])`.

As for the Phoenix part, that should be a separate question.